# Share actions between domains

Tags: redux, redux-thunk

Usually I use redux-saga, but currently I need redux-thunk. I'm using ducks for modular structure and now for example I have two ducks: `auth` and `user` with async actions below:

**auth-duck.js**

```
register(credentials) {
    return dispatch => {
        dispatch(actions.registerRequest());
        return service.requestRegister(credentials)
            .then((response) => {
                dispatch(actions.registerSuccess(...));

                // Here I need to dispatch some action from user-duck.js
            })
            .catch(() => dispatch(actions.registerError(...)))
    }
}
```

**user-duck.js**

```
fetchUser() {
    return dispatch => {...}
}
```

I really don't know how to not mess these two modules and dispatch `fetchUser` after successful `register`.

I could return `register` result (e.g. token or something else) to container from here it was dispatched and then using chaining dispatch `fetchUser`.

**AuthContainer.js**

```
_onSubmit() {
    this.props.register().then(() => this.props.fetchUser);
}
```

But I don't know is it the best way to manage such operations with redux-thunk?

Comment: That seems *okay* as long as `_onSubmit` doesn't get more complex in the future. I'd probably put that logic inside `mapDispatchToProps` instead though, personally. That way your component doesn't have to know anything about the actions.

Comment: @DonovanM yes, you are right, `mapDispatchToProps` better then methods in component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a long search I found two options how to share the logic from separate domains.
**The first one** is to use `mapDispatchToProps` (Thanks **@DonovanM**), just like this:

```
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
   return {
       login: (credentials) => {
           return dispatch(authActions.login(credentials)).then(
               () => dispatch(userActions.fetchUser())
           );
       }
   }
}
```

`login` function returns `Promise` thats why we can chain it to another one.

**And the second** possible option:
Use something like a "bridge" file in our case it is **app-sagas.js**

**app-duck.js**

```
import {actions as authActions} from './auth-duck.js';
import {actions as userActions} from './user-duck.js';

export function doLogin(credentials) {
    return dispatch => {
        return dispatch(authAction.login(credentials)).then(
            () => dispatch(userActions.fetchUser())
        );
    }
}
```

In the second case we can place all logic into ducks and avoid spreading the logic within containers. But I guess it is possible to combine both methods.

Answer (score 1):

There is no rule thunks can only make one HTTP request. If you need to fetch the user after login, then fetch it.

```
const login = credentials => dispatch => {
    fetchLogin(credentials).then(() => {
        dispatch({ type: "LoginSuccess" })
        return fetchUser()
    }).then(() => {
        dispatch({ type: "UserFetched" })
    })
}
```

If you want to reuse the user fetch action, then dispatch a thunk from a thunk.

```
const fetchCurrentUser = login => dispatch => {
    return fetchUser(login.userId).then(user => {
        dispatch({ type: "UserLoad" })
        return user
    })
}

const login = credentials => dispatch => {
    return fetchLogin(credentials).then(login => {
        dispatch({ type: "LoginSuccess" })
        return dispatch(fetchCurrentUser(login))
    }
}
```

In one of my apps, I call 7 action thunks after successful login.

Comment: Thanks **@AJcodez** for your answer. The idea of ducks is to have independent modules in order to provide loose coupling. So login duck mustn't know anything about user duck.